# How to use get_template_part instead of include_once?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm including a file by `include_once`:

```
include_once( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . '/recaptchalib.php' );
```

However I get warning from theme check plugin:

```
INFO: The theme appears to use include or require. 
If these are being used to include separate sections of a template from independent files, 
then get_template_part() should be used instead.
```

How can I include the above file using the `get_template_part`?

Answer (score 2):

The template part works like this.
If you have file in main folder then you can do like this:

```
get_template_part('recaptchalib');
```

In this example the file name is `recaptchalib.php`.

and if you have file in any other directory then you should called it by

```
 get_template_part('templates/layouts', 'recaptchalib');
```

In this example file is in `templates/layouts` and file name is `recaptchalib.php`.

Comment: Changed your answer a bit to get it just right ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [Codex page for `get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), you fill find the following usage:

> Load a template part into a template (other than header, sidebar, footer). Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code and an easy way for child themes to replace sections of their parent theme.
>
> Includes the named template part for a theme or if a name is specified then a specialized part will be included. If the theme contains no `{slug}.php` file then no template will be included.

```
<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>
```

> **$slug**
> (string) (required) The slug name for the generic template.
> Default: None
>
> **$name**
> (string) (optional) The name of the specialized template.
> Default: None

That means you can use the following:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'recaptchalib' ); ?>
```

You can use this to include every file in your theme directory.